# How do I call a MinimalAPI that features a Stream parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET 6 MinimalAPI designed to put a simple wrapper around a library that stores files.  It looks like this:

```
app.MapPost(
    "DocumentStorage/CreateDocument/{documentId:int}",
    (IDocumentStorageManager documentStorageManager, int documentId, Stream stream) =>
    {
        return documentStorageManager.CreateDocument(documentId, stream);
    });
```

The `IDocumentStorageManager` is injected, and the CreateDocument method simply returns a string of the newly stored document's URI.

I can't seem to figure out how to hit this method using an `HttpClient`.  Below is the very basic version of what I've been trying, but I've attempted many different variations.

```
using (var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var uri = $"http://localhost:1234/DocumentStorage/CreateDocument/{123}";
    var content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
        HttpMethod.Post,
        uri)
        {
            Content = content
        };

    var result = new HttpClient().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
}
```

Regardless of the variation used, I get this as the response:

```
{
    StatusCode: 415,
    ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type',
    Version: 1.1,
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
    Headers:
    {
        Date: Tue, 08 Nov 2022 21:41:48 GMT
        Server: Kestrel
        Content-Length: 0
    }
}
```

The variations I've tried have utilized several different headers, content-type specifications, form data content and other stuff.  I would think there's a straight forward way to pass a `Stream` to an `HttpClient` POST call, but I'm not seeing it out there on the ol' WWW.

Comment: You can't receive a stream in a controller like this. It looks like you're just trying to post a file to an API, there are plenty of ways to do that if you search.

Comment: @DavidG - Are you saying the minimal API cannot have a signature that has a Stream parameter? I am indeed posting a file to an endpoint, and hoping to get there without fully loading the file into memory on the server side, but either way, there is a requirement to use a minimal API, no controller. Unfortunately, searching has gotten me a sea of results, running the gamut of approaches going back to .NET 3.5, none of which have quite worked.